Bitcoin to Ethereum atomic swap with PTLCs
According to this, it wouldn't be possible to use PTLCs to swap to Ethereum:

Cross-chain atomic swaps based on adaptor signatures, or at least semi-scriptless adaptor signature schemes designed for the ECDSA curve, are incompatible with Ethereum. This is because Ethereum uses the account model, not the UTXO model. Specifically, in adaptor signature-based atomic swaps, refund transactions must be pre-signed. However, in the Ethereum system, transactions cannot be pre-signed without knowing the nonce. Therefore, one party can send a transaction between the pre-signature and the transaction execution, invalidating the pre-signed transaction (because the nonce has been used and cannot be reused).

But as I understand it, someone sending you a transaction in Ethereum would only increment their nonce, not yours, so your pre-signed transaction wouldn't be invalidated. Am I misunderstanding something?
Are there any other Bitcoin-specific things that would be blockers for an Ethereum PTLC? I know that Schnorr signatures are also not well supported on Ethereum.
